# Gcloud ssh permission denied after running command

Tags: gcloud

I receive Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].

error after I run:
gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone us-east1-d  --command "tar -xf archive.tar"

I can run --command "ls -al" which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the user you're ssh-ing as can't run the command. If that's the case when you run `gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone us-east1-d` and issue command `tar -xf archive.tar` you should see the same error. Do you?

Comment: If I login using: gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone us-east1-d
and then issue the tar -xf archive.tar command it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did a work around. Instead of using tar I send the folder as is upon user request.